# Change iOS Language without Restarting the app only with Images(around 300)

Tags: ios, localization

I am working on a app with 300 images(no text) and trying to change the language with button click and without restarting.

```
- (IBAction)changeArab:(id)sender {

NSArray* languages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", @"fr", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
}
```

I am able to change the language when i am restarting the app with the code above.

I localized all the images with the required language, is there anyway where i can reload the view once the language is change or change the app one the fly.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use an image with two languages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change it without restarting app.

You have to use NSNotificationCenter.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(localeChanged:)
                                                     name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:nil];

}

- (void)localeChanged:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    // the user changed the locale 

  //code to update views or data set.
}
```

If you have not localized your app in that way. Then Add Custom Observer to Notification Center and when user change language in your custom settings view then it will generate local notification which will be captured by application did receive notification and from that you can load all your view's again.

Comment: Strictly speaking this won't change the language, it will listen for a change in the system language so you can update your App accordingly. The user has to go to the iOS settings App in order to change the language for the OS. If you implement localization properly using the Apple tools you shouldn't need to manually update anything like this.